# Why can not Google Dataprep handle the encoding in my log files?

Tags: google-cloud-dataprep

We are receiving big log files each month. Before loading them into Google BigQuery they need to be converted from fixed with to delimited. I found a good [article](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Parse-fixed-width-file-and-infer-columns_66194010) on how to do that in Google Dataprep. However, there seems to be something wrong with the encoding.

Each time a Swedish Character appears in the log file, the Split function seems to add another space. This messes up the rest of the columns, as can be seen in the attached screenshot.

I can't determine the correct encoding of the log files, but I know they are being created by pretty old Windows servers in Poland.

Can anyone advice on how to solve this challenge?

[Screenshot of the issue in Google Dataprep.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTFU7.png)

Answer (score 0):

What us the exact recipe you are using ? Do you use (split every x ) ?
When I used in a test case an ISO Latin1 text and ingested it as ISO 8859-1, the output was as expected and only the display was off
Can you try the same ?
Would it be possible to share an example input file with one or two rows ?

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Sebastian! Here is a [sample file](https://www.enhanza.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/sample-file.txt). I hope it still holds the same encoding after I've opened and saved it in Sublime Text to shorten it.
I used the transformation "split" with the following "sequence of positions" (the file has fixed widths): 10,20,21,27,33,37,46,54,71,81,87,89,97,103,111,117,122,129,136,137,139,149,151,161,163,173,181,191,201,211,221,231,232,235,236,237,238,248,258,268,271,281,282,292,302,308,343,347,350.

Comment: Hi Jon, I was able to replicate it and there is a defect for this issue filed ( byte length based split rather then character based split ) and it will in the next major release update

Comment: Thank you, Sebastian! Do you have any clue on when this major release is schedule?

Comment: Dear Sebastian. Do you know when this "next major release update" will be released?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any ETA that I can communicate, since this is a Google product. If you provide their GCP support team this thread as reference, they should be able to provide you with the proper feedback

Comment: I will monitor the [reales notes](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/release-notes) for Google Dataprep and announce here when the new major update has been released.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you can use the RegEx, which should work. 
It's unfortunately a bit more complex, because you would have to use multiple regex splits. Here's an example for the first two splits after 10 characters each /.{10}/ and split on //

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for spending the time, Sebastian. Since it's (as you mentioned) a know issue by Google and since it will be addressed in the next major release I decided to wait for that. Still, knowing that really helped!